# Calculating CPU usage from /proc/stat

Tags: bash

When reading `/proc/stat`, I get these return values:

```
cpu  20582190 643 1606363 658948861 509691 24 112555 0 0 0                      
cpu0 3408982 106 264219 81480207 19354 0 35 0 0 0                               
cpu1 3395441 116 265930 81509149 11129 0 30 0 0 0                               
cpu2 3411003 197 214515 81133228 418090 0 1911 0 0 0                            
cpu3 3478358 168 257604 81417703 30421 0 29 0 0 0                               
cpu4 1840706 20 155376 83328751 1564 0 7 0 0 0                                  
cpu5 1416488 15 171101 83410586 1645 13 108729 0 0 0                            
cpu6 1773002 7 133686 83346305 25666 10 1803 0 0 0                              
cpu7 1858207 10 143928 83322929 1819 0 8 0 0 0
```

Some sources state to read only the first four values to calculate CPU usage, while some sources say to read all the values.

Do I read only the first four values to calculate CPU utilization; the values `user`, `nice`, `system`, and `idle`? Or do I need all the values? Or not all, but more than four? Would I need `iowait`, `irq`, or `softirq`?

```
cpu  20582190 643 1606363
```

Versus the entire line.

```
cpu  20582190 643 1606363 658948861 509691 24 112555 0 0 0
```

**Edits:** Some sources also state that `iowait` is added into `idle`.

When calculating a specific process' CPU usage, does the method differ?

Comment: It depends on what you understand "CPU usage" to mean. You obviously know what all the columns are, so I'm guessing you've read the man page and know what they *mean*, too. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: I was originally confused on why some people said to only use the first four columns in calculating CPU utilization (percentage of thread usage 0-100%). Although to my current understanding, all columns are should be used, but I don't know if there's a situation like that one column is already added into another. I heard `iowait` is apparently pre-added to `idle`, but I am unsure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/proc.5.html) states that it varies with architecture, and also gives a couple of examples describing how they are different:

> In Linux 2.6 this line includes three additional columns: ...
>
> Since Linux 2.6.11, there is an eighth  column, ...
>
> Since Linux 2.6.24, there is a ninth column, ...

When "some people said to only use..." they were probably not taking these into account.

Regarding whether the calculation differs across CPUs: You will find lines related to "cpu", "cpu0", "cpu1", ... in /proc/stat. The "cpu" fields are all aggregates (not averages) of corresponding fields for the individual CPUs. You can check that for yourself with a simple awk one-liner.

> cpu  84282 747 20805 1615949 44349 0 308 0 0 0
>
> cpu0 26754 343 9611 375347 27092 0 301 0 0 0
>
> cpu1 12707 56 2581 422198 5036 0 1 0 0 0
>
> cpu2 33356 173 6160 394561 7508 0 4 0 0 0
>
> cpu3 11464 174 2452 423841 4712 0 1 0 0 0